# How to write withinOP postgis extension in kotlin-exposed?

Tags: kotlin, postgis, kotlin-exposed

this is piece of code make me able to run postgis `&&` with geometry as input

```
private class WithinOp(val expr1: Expression<*>, val geom: PGgeometry) : Op<Boolean>() {
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) {
        expr1.toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder)
        queryBuilder.args
        queryBuilder.append(" && \'${geom.value}\'")
    }
```

how query looks like:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE table."location" && 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((1 2,2 2,2 3,1 3,1 2))`

For now it is became a problem since && is searching by `minimum bounding rectangle`. It is not accurate enough for my goals so I want to replace it with more accurate postgis method such as `ST_Intersects`

but when I updated my builder it is not working because exposed wrongly builded this query:

```kotlin
private class WithinOp(val expr1: Expression<*>, val geom: PGgeometry) : Op<Boolean>() {
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) {
        expr1.toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder)
        queryBuilder.args
        queryBuilder.append(" ST_Intersects($expr1, \'${geom.value}\'")
```

query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table."location" ST_Intersects(waycare.sql.Table.location, 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((1 2,2 2,2 3,1 3,1 2))` - incorrect

correct syntax is :`SELECT * FROM table WHERE  ST_Intersects(table."location",'SRID=4326;POLYGON((1 2,2 2,2 3,1 3,1 2))`

How to build nice extension in exposed it is not pretty documented. But I have to find some soulution. Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [CustomFunction](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Functions#custom-functions) here. I didn't test code below, but it should be enough to catch the idea:

```
class ST_IntersectsFunction(val expr1: Expression<*>, val geom: String) 
   : CustomFunction<Boolean>("ST_Intersects", BooleanColumnType(), expr1, stringParam(geom.value))
```

And to use:

```
 table.select { ST_IntersectsFunction(table.id, geom) eq true }
```